# Compare two slices

Tags: go, comparison, slice

Is there a way in Go to compare two slices and get the elements in slice X that are not in slice Y and vice versa?

```
    X := []int{10, 12, 12, 12, 13}
    Y := []int{12, 14, 15}

func compare(X, Y []int)  

calling compare(X, Y)   
    result1 := []int{10, 12, 12, 13} // if you're looking for elements in slice X that are not in slice Y

calling compare(Y, X)
    result2 := []int{14, 15} // if you're looking for elements in slice Y that are not in slice X
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    X := []int{10, 12, 12, 12, 13}
    Y := []int{12, 14, 15}

    fmt.Println(compare(X, Y))
    fmt.Println(compare(Y, X))
}

func compare(X, Y []int) []int {
    m := make(map[int]int)

    for _, y := range Y {
        m[y]++
    }

    var ret []int
    for _, x := range X {
        if m[x] > 0 {
            m[x]--
            continue
        }
        ret = append(ret, x)
    }

    return ret
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/4DujR2staI

Comment: It would be interesting to see if the same code could be refactored to run at O(n) instead of O(n^2)

Comment: The complexity of this code is actually O(n*log(n)) (if map complexity is O(log(n)), I think it's actually lower as it's implemented as a (multi-level) hash map).

Comment: I'm not sure if the performance can be improved if the slices aren't sorted. If they are something like Laremere's approach can be used.

Answer (score 8):

If order is not important, and the sets are large, you should use a set implementation, and use its diff function to compare them.

Sets are not part of the standard library, but you can use this library for example, you can initialize a set automatically from a slice with it. https://github.com/deckarep/golang-set

Something like this:

```
import (
    set "github.com/deckarep/golang-set"
    "fmt"
    )

func main() {
    //note that the set accepts []interface{}
    X := []interface{}{10, 12, 12, 12, 13}
    Y := []interface{}{12, 14, 15}

    Sx := set.NewSetFromSlice(X)
    Sy := set.NewSetFromSlice(Y)
    result1 := Sx.Difference(Sy)
    result2 := Sy.Difference(Sx)

    fmt.Println(result1)
    fmt.Println(result2)
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for an implementation that's independent of any external library, ordering not important..

Comment: @jwesonga you can just take this library and put it in your source tree, why implement yet another set?

Comment: As miku pointed out I'm looking for a simpler implementation, a custom function

Comment: @jwesonga IMHO in this case you should not sweat it - it's not less efficient or anything to use a full set implementation, and you could have used the time you spent implementing it on more important stuff - like other features. Or debating stuff on SO ;)

Comment: @jwesonga, someone posted your question to [/r/golang](http://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/26inib/so_golang_how_to_compare_two_int_slices/), seems there's some code, too ...

Answer (score 4):

All of the solutions provided fail to precisely answer the question asked.  Instead of the differences in the slices, the solutions provide the differences of the sets of elements in the slices.

Specifically, instead of the intended example of:

```
    X := []int{10, 12, 12, 12, 13}
    Y := []int{12, 14, 15}

func compare(X, Y []int)  

calling compare(X, Y)   
    result1 := []int{10, 12, 12, 13} // if you're looking for elements in slice X that are not in slice Y

calling compare(Y, X)
    result2 := []int{14, 15}
```

The provided solutions will result in:

```
result1 := []int{10,13}
result2 := []int{14,15}
```

To yield strictly the example result, a different method is required.  Here are two solutions:

**If the slices are already sorted:**

This solution may be faster if you sort your slices, and then call compare.  It'll definitely be faster if your slices are already sorted.

```
func compare(X, Y []int) []int {
    difference := make([]int, 0)
    var i, j int
    for i < len(X) && j < len(Y) {
        if X[i] < Y[j] {
            difference = append(difference, X[i])
            i++
        } else if X[i] > Y[j] {
            j++
        } else { //X[i] == Y[j]
            j++
            i++
        }
    }
    if i < len(X) { //All remaining in X are greater than Y, just copy over
        finalLength := len(X) - i + len(difference)
        if finalLength > cap(difference) {
            newDifference := make([]int, finalLength)
            copy(newDifference, difference)
            copy(newDifference[len(difference):], X[i:])
            difference = newDifference
        } else {
            differenceLen := len(difference)
            difference = difference[:finalLength]
            copy(difference[differenceLen:], X[i:])
        }
    }
    return difference
}
```

[Go Playground version](http://play.golang.org/p/U1Y-uuYIFD)

**Unsorted Version using maps**

```
func compareMapAlternate(X, Y []int) []int {
    counts := make(map[int]int)
    var total int
    for _, val := range X {
        counts[val] += 1
        total += 1
    }
    for _, val := range Y {
        if count := counts[val]; count > 0 {
            counts[val] -= 1
            total -= 1
        }
    }
    difference := make([]int, total)
    i := 0
    for val, count := range counts {
        for j := 0; j < count; j++ {
            difference[i] = val
            i++
        }
    }
    return difference
}
```

[Go Playground version](http://play.golang.org/p/BUYjAmaft1)

**Edit:**  I've created a benchmark for testing my two version (with the map having a slight modification where it deletes zero values from the map).  It won't run on Go Playground because Time doesn't work properly on it, so I ran it on my own computer.

compareSort sorts the slice and calls the iterated version of compare, and compareSorted runs afters compareSort but relies on the slice already being sorted.

```
Case: len(X)== 10000 && len(Y)== 10000
--compareMap time: 4.0024ms
--compareMapAlternate time: 3.0225ms
--compareSort time: 4.9846ms
--compareSorted time: 1ms
--Result length == 6754 6754 6754 6754
Case: len(X)== 1000000 && len(Y)== 1000000
--compareMap time: 378.2492ms
--compareMapAlternate time: 387.2955ms
--compareSort time: 816.5619ms
--compareSorted time: 28.0432ms
--Result length == 673505 673505 673505 673505
Case: len(X)== 10000 && len(Y)== 1000000
--compareMap time: 35.0269ms
--compareMapAlternate time: 43.0492ms
--compareSort time: 385.2629ms
--compareSorted time: 3.0242ms
--Result length == 3747 3747 3747 3747
Case: len(X)== 1000000 && len(Y)== 10000
--compareMap time: 247.1561ms
--compareMapAlternate time: 240.1727ms
--compareSort time: 400.2875ms
--compareSorted time: 17.0311ms
--Result length == 993778 993778 993778 993778
```

As you can see, if the array is sorted not using maps is much faster, but using maps is faster than sorting it and then using the iterated approach.  For small cases sorting may be quick enough that it should be used, but the benchmark would finish to quickly to be timed.

Comment: Note that in the sorted version, the `if` block for  `// All remaining in X are greater than Y, just copy over` can be significantly simplified to use a sub-slice `remaining := X[i:]` and `difference = append(difference, remaining...)` and Go will handle checking capacity and copying automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to reinvent the wheel (and then maintain it) with custom algos, you can use [`github.com/r3labs/diff/v2`](https://github.com/r3labs/diff).

The diff returns a changelog that you can inspect to find exactly what changed, in the form of `create`/`update`/`delete` entries. The changelog can also be marshalled to JSON:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "github.com/r3labs/diff/v2"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    x := []int{10, 12, 12, 12, 13}
    y := []int{12, 14, 15}
    ch, _ := diff.Diff(x, y)
    json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout).Encode(ch)
}
```

It prints the changelog:

```
[{"type":"delete","path":["0"],"from":10,"to":null},{"type":"update","path":["2"],"from":12,"to":15},{"type":"delete","path":["3"],"from":12,"to":null},{"type":"delete","path":["4"],"from":13,"to":null},{"type":"create","path":["1"],"from":null,"to":14}]
```

The changelog essentially describes the operations necessary to obtain the second slice from the first.

The library also provides patch-like functionality. You can pass the changelog right into `diff.Patch` and apply the changes to the target value:

```
    diff.Patch(ch, &x)
    fmt.Println(x) // [12 14 15] just like the 'y' slice
```

Note that the default behavior of this differ is to ignore slice element order. So if you diff `[]int{12, 14, 15}` and `[]int{12, 15, 14}` it will produce an empty changelog.

To account for item ordering, use the option `diff.SliceOrdering(true)`:

```
func main() {
    x := []int{12, 15, 14}
    y := []int{12, 14, 15}
    ch, _ := diff.Diff(x, y, diff.SliceOrdering(true))
    json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout).Encode(ch)
    // [{"type":"update","path":["1"],"from":15,"to":14},{"type":"update","path":["2"],"from":14,"to":15}]

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Dragging in a set implementation might be overkill. [This should be enough](http://play.golang.org/p/xd8V03Xqsp):

```
func diff(X, Y []int) []int {

  diff := []int{}
  vals := map[int]struct{}{}

  for _, x := range X {
    vals[x] = struct{}{}
  }

  for _, x := range Y {
    if _, ok := vals[x]; !ok {
      diff = append(diff, x)
    }
  }

  return diff
}
```

A bloom filter can be added if the slices get really big.

Comment: your implementation won't yield any of the results

Comment: IMHO dragging in a copy-pasted half implementation of a set is worse than importing a set library that does just the same, provided it's well written and not bloated.

Comment: @jwesonga yes it does. @ Not_a_Golfer debatable.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer, I think there are use cases, where you are not worse off by using a small custom function instead of an external library. Beside, even if you use the library most of the time, you might want to *know* about a simple version anyway.

Comment: I'm avoiding downvoting your response but it's pretty obvious that if I pass my two slices to your func I won't get result1 or result2

Comment: @iliacholy Go facilitates code reuse in such a beautiful way, it seems redundant to reinvent the wheel in this case. But it's debatable. It's true that dependencies have their hidden costs. But then again, why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: "Go facilitates code reuse in such a beautiful way" with its lack of dependency versioning? Also, it's 17 loc ... not exactly reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score -1):

At the moment I answer this question, go version is 1.17.3

We can use a built-in package: [reflect](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#)

The package provides a very useful function [DeepEqual](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#DeepEqual) that fits your requirement

```golang
reflect.DeepEqual(X, Y)
```